# PL/SQL: Forecasting sales depending on what date it is

Tags: oracle, plsql

Declaration: I am very new to PL/SQL. I use SAS and Python previously.

I have to forecast sale for each day for the next 2 weeks. If it is weekday (say Monday), I have to use historical sale on those weekdays (Monday) to forecast the coming days (Mondays). If it is holiday (say Christmas), I have to use sale on historical Christmas.
In python, I would loop through each day/observation, check if it is a holiday or not and use an appropriate function which I wrote in each case to pick out the appropriate days and do my calculation.

What would be the approach in PL/SQL? How do I loop through each observation? Can I even do this? To my understanding, the steps which I would approach this issue are:

1. Get a list of the next 2 weeks, create a column (let's call WEEKDAY) that indicates what weekday it is. This can be done via a loop?
2. I would have to write a function and check if the day/obs is a holiday (I have a table that contains holidays).
3. For obs where it is not a holiday, use the corresponding previous weekdays
4. For obs where it is a holiday, use the historical holidays.

Is my logic correct? 
I am also stuck at creating functions and loop, so if anyone can help, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Before making any assumptions could you provide us some sample data or previously written code blocks etc. Please ? Yes you can find answers to all of your questions in plsql. But if you want us to solve them for you at least you can show us how hard did you try before asking it ? Please ?

Comment: I do not think Sales Forecasting is something that can be done in PL/SQL. Usually it take good machine learning models to forecast your sales (usually in Python but not limited). Which is a feature that PL/SQL does not have.

Comment: Only if you are trying to emulate something like that which will probably not have the same accuracy as a good trained model, but still give you some results then you should start by learning PL/SQL syntax and check if your Python logic can be translated to PL/SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Use SQL for the heavy lifting and use PL/SQL mostly to glue your SQL statements together. For example, you can use the `REGR` functions to create a simple ordinary least squares forecast like in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55135131/409172).

Using SQL is going to feel weird at first, because it's a declarative approach instead of traditional imperative programming. For example, don't loop through each individual day - calculate the entire forecast and then `GROUP BY` the day. And don't create a function to check if it's a holiday - join to the holiday table and use a SQL expression to check if the day is a holiday. If you're lucky, you can build the entire forecast in a single SQL statement.

Using declarative code will probably be more work the first time. But when done well, the results will be much faster and simpler than a procedural approach. (At least compared against using plain PL/SQL.) For example, one nice side affect of using SQL is that adding multi-threading can be as easy as adding a single `/*+ parallel */` hint.

If you need more powerful forecasting algorithms, take a look at [Oracle Data Mining](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/advanced-analytics/odm.html), which is part of the Machine Learning/Advanced Analytics package. That option has been around for a long time but was only recently made available for free.